# Checking if input is an integer

Tags: python, integer

I am not sure how to use `isinstance`, but here is what I tried:

```
age = int(input("Enter your Age: "))
if isinstance(age,int):
    continue
else:
    print ("Not an integer")
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also will this make my program terminate? Or ask me to re-enter my age?

I want it to keep asking me to re-enter if input is not an integer.

Comment: because you have assumed your input can be "int"ed.

Comment: if my answer solved your problem please check it as answer

Answer (score 6):

That's not going to work if the user enters something other than an integer, because the call to `int()` will trigger a `ValueError`. And if `int()` does succeed, there's no need to check `isinstance()` any longer. Also, `continue` only makes sense within a `for` or `while` loop. Instead, do this:

```
while True:      # keep looping until we break out of the loop
    try:
        age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
        break    # exit the loop if the previous line succeeded
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter an integer!")
# If program execution makes it here, we know that "age" contains an integer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
isinstance(object, class-or-type-or-tuple) -> bool

age = int(input("Enter your Age: "))

In [6]: isinstance(age, int)
Out[6]: True
```

Try recursive function. with `try except`

```
def solve():
    try:
        age = int(input('enter age: '))
        solve()
    except ValueError:
        print('invalid value')
solve()
```

Comment: This is just as wrong as the OP's original code (even without the typo).

Comment: @TimPietzcker sorry that was my bad i didn't read question completely, i updated my code please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun :) another possible answer without handling exceptions (probably inefficient):

```
age=raw_input('Enter your age: ')
while  len ([ii for ii in age if not ii in [str(jj) for jj in range(9)]]) > 0:
    print 'It\'s not an integer\n'
    age=raw_input('Enter your age: ')
age=int(age)
```