# i am doing a triangle identifier and my problem is that i cant get over if the user inputs a string

Tags: python

so I am doing my first project which is a triangle identifier through sides, I came across this issue where if someone wrote a letter the program would crash since you can't float the input when it's a string  so I tried a few methods (try: except I tried:

if x == str and x != int and x != float:
print("please choose a viable unit ")
but it now displays that even when I have normal numbers like (4,6,6 )
I only did the x input to know if it works in the first place
my final code :

```py
print("please input the sides of the triangle")
x = input("the first side = ")
y = input(" the second side = ")
z = input("the third side = ")

if str(x) == x and int(x) != x and float(x) != x:
    print("please choose a viable unit ")

elif x == y == z:
    print("the triangle is equilateral ")
elif x == y or y == z or x == z:
    print("the triangle is isosceles")
elif x != y or x != z or y != z:
    print("the triangle is scalene")
elif(x*x) + (y*y) == (z*z) or (z*z) + (y*y) == (x*x) or (z*z) + (x*x) == (y*y):
    print("the triangle is also right")
```

Comment: Your title should summarize your question; its purpose is to help other people with the same problem find your question and learn from its answers. Think of what you're writing here like a FAQ entry, not a forum post.

Comment: That said, if, say, `x == '3.14'`, then `float(x) != x` will _always_ be true, because `'3.14' != 3.14`. The string `'3.14'` and the float `3.14` are two different values, just like the string `'3'` and the integer `3` are two different values.

Comment: i changed the title is it okay now ? + what would you suggest me doing

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
if str(x) == x and int(x) != x and float(x) != x:
```

does not actually turn `x` into either an `int` or a `float`; it can also never be true, because it's not possible for `x` to be all of those types at once.  `x` is always going to be a `str` because `input` always returns a `str`.  The only thing this line can do is raise a `ValueError` (which will cause your script to exit since you haven't caught it) if `x` is a value that can't be converted into an `int`.

What you want to do is turn `x`, `y`, and `z` into `float`s as soon as you read them:

```
try:
    x = float(input("the first side = "))
    y = float(input(" the second side = "))
    z = float(input("the third side = "))
except ValueError:
    print("please choose a viable unit ")
    exit()
```

After this point, if the script hasn't exited, `x`, `y`, and `z` are guaranteed to be `float` values, and you can perform math operations on them without encountering `TypeError`s.

Comment: this makes perfect sense thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

First: Do everyone a favor and change your title to something along the lines of "Help with Python Input and Ints"

Second:
When you use a python input, it reads that input as a string. So, in order to do any math with that string, it needs to NOT be a string, and instead considered a number.

That being said the inputs will have to be along the lines of

```
foo = float(input("bar"))
```

Edit: You also mentioned that you were having issues if the user inputs a string. You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27310631/checking-if-input-is-an-integer) for reference on how to implement a try except case for that instance

Comment: i tried that but as i said since you cant float a string it automatically  gives an error if the user inputs a string